# How to create dict of dicts using csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary

I'd like to create a dictionary with the key's being the first row of the csv file and the value's being a dictionary of {first column: corresponding column to row} For example, test.csv

```
Header1, Header2, Header3
A,       1,       10
B,       2,       20
C,       3,       30
```

I am using `data.drop(['Header1'], 1)` to drop `Header1`.

I would like the resulting dict to be:

```
{'Header2':{A:1, B:2, C:3},'Header3':{A:10, B:20, C:30}}
```

Should I be using `csv.DictReader`? Or numpy arrays instead?

Comment: Dont you mean `{'Header2':{A:1, B:2, C:3},'Header3':{A:10, B:20, C:30}}` ?

Comment: Just do `to_dict`

Comment: If your issue is resolved please mark one of the answers as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using pandas,

```
df = pd.read_csv(testcsv, index_col=['Header1'], sep=',\s+')
df.to_dict()
```

Output:

```
{'Header2': {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3}, 'Header3': {'A': 10, 'B': 20, 'C': 30}}
```

Comment: This is saying ValueError: Index Header1 invalid?

Comment: Try `index_col=[0]` because it doesn't appear your csv first column is 'Header1'.

Answer (score 0):

Another example without pandas:

```
import csv

with open('data_all.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    dicts = {entry:{} for entry in next(reader)[1:]}
    for row in reader:
        index = 0
        for _dict in dicts.values():
            index+=1
            _dict[row[0]]=row[index]

    print(dicts)
```

`{' Header2': {'A': ' 1', 'B': ' 2', 'C': ' 3'}, ' Header3': {'A': ' 10', 'B': ' 20', 'C': ' 30'}}`